# Blocking queue not working in java, I can put more element than the defined size of blocking queue

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have declared a BlockingQueue of size 1

`final BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);`.

But I am able to add more than 1 element into the queue. I am sure I am missing something in this like this is the core property of BlockingQueue. Here is the code from java docs.

```
    /**
     * Creates an {@code ArrayBlockingQueue} with the given (fixed)
     * capacity and default access policy.
     *
     * @param capacity the capacity of this queue
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code capacity < 1}
     */
    public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        this(capacity, false);
    }
```

But when I am implementing I am able to produce more than 1 element, according to me if the size of the BlockingQueue is 1 then after producing 1 element it should wait for the consumer to consume the element.
Here is the code and the output of the code.

**I need an explanation for this, can you please help me with this.**

I have tried google search and StackOverflow with no success.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class BlockingQueueTestWorking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);

        Runnable producer = () -> {
            try {
                int iterator = 0;
                while (true) {
                    if (iterator++ == 10)
                        break;

                    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    Integer i = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                    blockingQueue.put(i);
                    System.out.println(name + " Producing:-> " + i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Runnable consumer = () -> {
            try {
                int iterator = 0;
                while (true) {
                    if (iterator++ == 10)
                        break;
                    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    Integer take = blockingQueue.take();
                    System.out.println(name + " Consuming:<- " + take);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Thread threadProducer = new Thread(producer);


        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        executor.execute(threadProducer);
        
        Thread threadConsumer = new Thread(consumer);
        executor.execute(threadConsumer);

        executor.shutdown();
    }

}

Output:
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 2
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 7
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 2
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 7
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 6
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 6
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 2
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 2
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 6
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 6
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 1
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 1
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 2
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 2
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 2
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 2
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 2
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 2
pool-1-thread-1 Producing:-> 4
pool-1-thread-2 Consuming:<- 4
```

Comment: How are you claiming you were able to add more than one element? Why don't you just run the producer alone? *Hint*: Don't rely on the order of the print statements

Comment: @user7 If you see the output, I am able to produce 2 elements. Please have a look at the output.

Comment: See my *Hint* in my comment

Comment: Consider a context switch between the two lines `Integer take = blockingQueue.take();` and `System.out.println(name + " Consuming:<- " + take);`

Comment: @user7 Thanks, I got it. If I am running the producer alone it is not taking more than one element. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the print to

```
System.out.println(String.format("[%s]", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + " Producing:-> " + i);
```

and

```
System.out.println(String.format("[%s]", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())) + name + " Consuming:<- " + take);
```

and you will see that they are actually not printed in the correct time order

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a race condition between both threads.

You believe it produced a second message **because you see the output of the producer before of the consumer one**. It was lucky and his `System.out` was processed before the consumer's one.

Try debugging it, and you'll see no second element is being added without the consumer reading the first one before. *Don't believe the order in console outputs*...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it.